# $\zeta(2 + it) = \zeta(2-it)$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Let $\zeta(s)$ denote the Riemann zeta-function. Show that $\zeta(2 + it) =
\zeta(2-it)$ for all real t.

Give some hints how to do this one.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The claim is wrong.

Comment: That doesn't look correct...check that, @analysis

Comment: I have written rightly, it is an assignment problem. There may be some typo. Why is it wrong? If you know the possible corresponding right statement please edit this one.

Comment: The argument part seems to be different (opposite sign). Check for example with $\;t=1\;$ in WA: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=value%20of%20Riemann%20zeta%20function%20at%20(2-i) , http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=value+of+Riemann+zeta+function+at+%282%2Bi%29

Comment: What seems to be true (and in fact it's easy to prove) is that both numbers' **modulus** is the same...

Answer (score 6):

The problem should read "Show that
$$ \overline{\zeta(2+it)}=\zeta(2-it)."$$  The 2 is arbitrary; it will hold for real part of $s$ any $\sigma>1$.  Complex conjugation is continuous, so you may pass it through the infinite series defining the zeta function.  (In fact this holds for all $\sigma$ once we have an analytic continuation.)

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, the claim is not correct. These two numbers are in fact complex conjugates.

If $f$ is any meromorphic function which takes real values on the real line, then $\overline{f(z)} = f(\overline{z})$ for all $z$. This follows from the [Schwartz reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) and from the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Only the real part of $\zeta(2 + it)$ is symmetric over $t=0$

[For a visual, see this plot where $-2 < t < 2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+im%28+zeta%282%2Bx+I%29+%29%2C+re%28+zeta%282%2Bx+I%29+%29%2C+x%2C+-2%2C2)

Like the others have said, something is missing, whether it be some kind of conjugation, a re(), or a modulus.